# Login my application using Instagram application

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, instagram-graph-api

Every time I log into my app using instagram it takes me to the webview to login using Instagram credentials and there is not any option to login using Instagram application as Facebook provides option on its webpage to login using FB application and redirects to FB app to get token.

I have tried instagram documentation but got no hint.

[Login using Instagram there is login using app option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJCjK.jpg)

[Login using FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmJS0.png)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?